# Transform working tikzpicture into \newcommand with arguments

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, tikz-pic

I am trying to transform the solution of [THIS](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/639366/203987) question

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{leadsheets}
\setchords{
  major-seven = \textsuperscript{$\Delta$} ,
  major-nine = \textsuperscript{$\Delta$9}
}

\begin{document}

\tikzmark{ii7}\writechord{Cmi7}\qquad
\tikzmark{V7}\writechord{F7}\qquad
\tikzmark{I}\writechord{Bbmaj7}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw[->]
    ([shift={(.3em,1em)}]pic cs:V7) to[bend left]
    ([shift={(.3em,1em)}]pic cs:I) ;
  \draw
    ([shift={(.3em,-.3em)}]pic cs:ii7)
    --++ (0,-1ex) -|
    ([shift={(.3em,-.3em)}]pic cs:V7) ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

into a function with three arguments. Here is my slighlty simplified attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcommand{\Test}[3]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw[->]
    ([shift={(.3em,1em)}]pic cs: #3) to[bend left]
    ([shift={(.3em,1em)}]pic cs: #1);
  \draw
    ([shift={(.3em,-.3em)}]pic cs: #2)
    --++ (0,-1ex) -|
    ([shift={(.3em,-.3em)}]pic cs: #3) ;
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
 \Test{I}{ii7}{V7}
 \end{document}
```

However, the outputs clearly has some issues, as in the picture below:

[image]

Can you spot the mistakes?

EDIT: I would like to be able to stack a bunch of those without any problem and in a compact way, similar to the example below:

```
\Test{C}{Dm7}{G7}
\Test{D}{Em7}{A7}
\Test{E}{Fm7}{B$/flat$7}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDITED based on OP comment.

RE-EDITED so that a unique `\tikzmark` is created even if the same chord name is re-used.

RE-RE-EDITED to give the OP's preferred chord order.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{leadsheets}

\newcounter{cdct}
\newcommand\Test[3]{\stepcounter{cdct}%
  \Testaux{\thecdct}{#1}{#2}{#3}}

\newcommand\Testaux[4]{%
\tikzmark{#1A}\writechord{#2}\qquad
\tikzmark{#1B}\writechord{#3}\qquad
\tikzmark{#1C}\writechord{#4}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw[->]
    ([shift={(.3em,1em)}]pic cs:#1B) to[bend left]
    ([shift={(.3em,1em)}]pic cs:#1C) ;
  \draw
    ([shift={(.3em,-.3em)}]pic cs:#1A)
    --++ (0,-1ex) -|
    ([shift={(.3em,-.3em)}]pic cs:#1B) ;
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\Test{Dm7}{G7}{C}
\Test{Em7}{A7}{D}
\Test{Fm7}{Bb7}{Eb}

\bigskip\Test{Dm7}{G7}{C}\par
\bigskip\Test{Em7}{A7}{D}\par
\bigskip\Test{Fm7}{Bb7}{Eb}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks. This kind of works, it just requires some minor adjustments, as it inherited two different problems from the previous functions, which appear when you stack a few of those. 1. You need to write the three lines ```\tikzmark{}``` every time you want to change the arguments (please correct me if I am wrong). 2.Both the bracket and the arrow seem to disappear.

Comment: @Phys Please see my edit to see if the latter approach is closer to what you want.  Note: 2 compilations are required.

Comment: Very close. But try stacking these ```\Test{Cmi7}{F7}{Bbmaj7} 

\Test{Dmi7}{G7}{Cmaj7} \Test{Cmi7}{F7}{Bbmaj7}```. It seems that both bracket and arrow are not inserted on duplicates chords, but only if they are different (I did compile twice). Perhaps, there should be some sort of reset command inside the function?

Comment: @Phys Fixed.  I stepped a counter and included the counter number as part of the tikzmark name, so that repeated use of a chord name generates a unique tikzmark.

Comment: Well done, works flawlessly now, thanks for your effort.

Comment: @Phys I made one final edit so that it doesn't get confused if you use the same chord name within the 3 arguments (I don't think you ever would).  Now I call the tikzmarks <count>A, <count>B, and <count>C, regardless of what the passed argument names are.

Comment: Nice. Also I mixed that ```B$/flat$``` with ```B$\flat$```, but actually the example here correctly inserts the right musical symbol by typing a simple ```Bb```, since it was used some chord definition. But that is a minor issue.

Comment: Sorry I just noticed one last thing, which would annoy a lot the music users. The order of the chords seems wrong (might be my fault, due to an initial error). The correct order should be i.e. Dm7--G7--C. Probably one of the # indices is wrong.

Comment: Ok, the function should be called in this way: ```\Test{Dm7}{G7}{C}```, no need to modify anything in the function itself. This is actually even more elegant, since it directly reminds of the ii-V-I cadence.

Comment: @Phys So, if called as `\Test{Dm7}{G7}{C}`, in what left to right order should the output look like?

Comment: Should be Dm7-G7-C. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Looks fine now. Just one last tiny thing: would you mind changing the ```E``` into ```Eb``` into the ```\Test{Fm7}{Bb7}{E}``` example (the correct one would be ```\Test{Fm7}{Bb7}{Eb}```)? I have been on this for several hours, and I missed this detail. Besides that, it's perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I am adding my own variation on the answer provided by Steven B. Segletes.

1-ii-subV7-I cadence is now included (dashed lines).

2-Both brackets and arrows have been adjusted and centered.

3-Mixed dashed/non-dashed cadences are allowed

4-Minor chords are expressed as `-` rather than `min`

5-Minor seven half-diminished chords are given by `-7b5`

You can delete options 4 and 5 by customizing the option in `\setchords{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{leadsheets}

\setchords{
 major-seven =$\Delta$7,%$\Delta$\arabicnumeral{7},
 major-nine = $\Delta$9,
 minor = -,
 half-dim = {($\flat 5$)}
}

\newcounter{cdct}
\newcommand\Dominant[3]{\stepcounter{cdct}%
  \Dominantaux{\thecdct}{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\newcommand\Dominantaux[4]{%
\tikzmark{#1#2}\writechord{#2}\qquad
\tikzmark{#1#3}\writechord{#3}\qquad
\tikzmark{#1#4}\writechord{#4}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw[->]
    ([shift={(.6em,1em)}]pic cs:#1#3) to[bend left]
    ([shift={(.2em,1em)}]pic cs:#1#4) ;
  \draw
    ([shift={(.8em,-.3em)}]pic cs:#1#2)
    --++ (0,-1ex) -|
    ([shift={(.6em,-.3em)}]pic cs:#1#3) ;
\end{tikzpicture}%
}


\newcommand\Subdominant[3]{\stepcounter{cdct}%
  \Subdominantaux{\thecdct}{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\newcommand\Subdominantaux[4]{%
\tikzmark{#1#2}\writechord{#2}\qquad
\tikzmark{#1#3}\writechord{#3}\qquad
\tikzmark{#1#4}\writechord{#4}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw[dashed,->]
    ([shift={(.6em,1em)}]pic cs:#1#3) to[bend left]
    ([shift={(.2em,1em)}]pic cs:#1#4) ;
  \draw[dashed]
    ([shift={(.8em,-.3em)}]pic cs:#1#2)
    --++ (0,-1ex) -|
    ([shift={(.6em,-.3em)}]pic cs:#1#3) ;
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
%
    
%%% Mixed %%%
\newcommand\Dominantmix[3]{\stepcounter{cdct}%
  \Dominantmixaux{\thecdct}{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\newcommand\Dominantmixaux[4]{%
\tikzmark{#1#2}\writechord{#2}\qquad
\tikzmark{#1#3}\writechord{#3}\qquad
\tikzmark{#1#4}\writechord{#4}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw[->]
    ([shift={(.6em,1em)}]pic cs:#1#3) to[bend left]
    ([shift={(.2em,1em)}]pic cs:#1#4) ;
  \draw[dashed]
    ([shift={(.8em,-.3em)}]pic cs:#1#2)
    --++ (0,-1ex) -|
    ([shift={(.6em,-.3em)}]pic cs:#1#3) ;
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand\Subdominantmix[3]{\stepcounter{cdct}%
  \Subdominantmixaux{\thecdct}{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\newcommand\Subdominantmixaux[4]{%
\tikzmark{#1#2}\writechord{#2}\qquad
\tikzmark{#1#3}\writechord{#3}\qquad
\tikzmark{#1#4}\writechord{#4}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw[dashed,->]
    ([shift={(.6em,1em)}]pic cs:#1#3) to[bend left]
    ([shift={(.2em,1em)}]pic cs:#1#4) ;
  \draw
    ([shift={(.8em,-.3em)}]pic cs:#1#2)
    --++ (0,-1ex) -|
    ([shift={(.6em,-.3em)}]pic cs:#1#3) ;
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

%


\begin{document}

\bigskip\Dominant{D-7}{G7}{Cmaj7}\par

\bigskip\Subdominant{Abmi7}{G7}{Gb7}\par

\bigskip\Subdominant{A-7}{Ab7}{G-7}\par

\bigskip\Dominant{Ami7/o}{D7}{Gmi7}\par

\bigskip\Dominant{Gmi7/o}{C7}{Fmaj7}\par

\bigskip\Subdominantmix{Ami7}{D7}{Dbmi7}\par

\bigskip\Dominantmix{Db-7}{C7}{Fmaj7}\par

\end{document}
```

[image]

Ideally, I would like to bring down the numbers, which are preset as `\textsuperscript{}`. If anyone knows how, please comment, thanks.

Comment: “I would like to bring down the numbers” – that's hardwired into `leadsheets` but is a reasonable wish. An option for this sounds like a feature request to me: https://github.com/cgnieder/leadsheets/issues